# Mongoose partial search for integers

Tags: javascript, search, mongoose, integer, partial

I am looking for a method which partial search for integers in mongoose.

I have a collection of objects that have a property called `incidentId` (Integer). I am passing the `incidentId` to the function (for exeample: 1) and I am expecting the results to be all the objects that have `incidentId` starting with 1 (for example: 1, 10, 11, 12 ... 100).

I tried using regular expression (before realizing I can't use it with numbers) like this:
`foundIncidents = await this.db.find({documentType: 'INCIDENT', 'incident.incidentId':{ $regex: incidentId, $options: 'i' }});`

I cannot modify the DB schema in order to change the `incidentId` to String.

If you need any more information let me know.

Thank you

Comment: If your question has been answered you should accept the answer and vote on it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you use MongoDb v4.0+ you can use the [aggregation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html) pipeline method [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) to convert the `int` to a `string` first.
And then use a `$regex` to match the `incidentId`.

Comment: Will this operation modify my DB permanently or just when it is called and the revert the ```incidentId``` back to int?

Comment: This does not change the DB.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a trick in older MongoDb versions prior to v4.0 to convert a `Number` to a `String`. It uses the aggregation operator [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) which accepts a `Number` as input (though docs say it only accepts a `String`).

Example:

```
"$project": {
    "stringId": {
       "$substr": [
          "$incidentId",
          0,
          -1
       ]
    }
 }
```

This converts the `incidentId` to `String` using the new fieldname `stringId`.

Comment: Unfortunately I just checked and I have 4.0 . Thanks anyway :D